# Why the screen brightness goes to the lowest all on a sudden?

Tags: brightness

I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but for some days, I am experiencing that all on a sudden my screen brightness goes to the lowest while I'm using it, and it stays like that, no change until I shut down and restart the machine— I can't change the brightness manually with hardware keys, and obviously not with the GUI as I can't see anything in the screen clearly. The very low light can be seen on the screen if and only if I make the surroundings extremely dark. Everything runs well, but seems like the screen is off due to the brightness. Once I shut down the system, and restart it, it runs normally for some 'times'. This 'time' depends on for how long I kept the machine turned off. If it is for short time, the 'time' is short and so on. How can I troubleshoot it?

Hardware: HP Probook 450 G2 (no change after buying, except replaced the HDD with SSD).
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5500.

Comment: Add details on your hardware and graphics card. Does it happen while you are actively using the computer, or does it happen after the computer is idle for some time? Can you then manually increase the brightness or not, or does brightness return when you hit a key? Please add as much specifics as you can to the question: use "edit" to update the actual question.

Comment: @vanadium, thanks for mentioning, I don't know about the graphics card, edited other information in the post.

Comment: `lshw -class display` will yield information on the graphical card.